# VB Program for college, Unsure what is wrong

Tags: vb.net

{"Conversion from string "" Senior (65+)"" to type 'Double' is not valid."}

Program is supposed to determine cost per month based on age, and extra perks for a sports club

[image: layout]

```
    Const Adult = 100D,
          Senior = 75D,
          Extras = 25D

    Const VBChecked As Decimal = 1
    Const VBUnchecked As Decimal = 0

    Dim Cost(3) As Decimal
    Cost(1) = 0D
    Cost(2) = 0D
    Cost(3) = 0D

    If (lst_Age.Items(1) = VBChecked) Then Cost(1) += Adult
    If (lst_Age.Items(2) = VBChecked) Then Cost(1) += Senior

    If (lst_Extras.Items(1) = VBChecked) Then Cost(2) += Extras
    If (lst_Extras.Items(2) = VBChecked) Then Cost(2) += Extras
    If (lst_Extras.Items(3) = VBChecked) Then Cost(2) += Extras

    Cost(3) = Cost(2) + Cost(1)
    Dim Output As Decimal = Cost(3)
    lbl_Output.Text = CDec(Output)
```

Comment: Bad title too.  Describe the problem

Comment: Not related to issue ; but arrays starts at index 0 you're lucky that array declaration in VB.Net isn't the length of the array but the index of the last element

Comment: Edited Question, first time on stack posting, but have perused through it before

Comment: What is the value of `lst_Age.Items(1)`?

Comment: We have no idea what `lst_Age` is but it apparently contains strings, so as the error explains, you cannot compare it to a Decimal (`VBChecked`)

Comment: another case of "not using [Option Strict](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs(v=vs.140).aspx)"

Comment: Item(1) = "Adults (18-64)"    
Item (2) = "Seniors (65+)"

Comment: ...so how does `If "Adults (18-64)" = 1 Then....` make any sense?

Comment: How should i be determining if an item in the list check box has been selected? that is what i need to do for the most part to determine the cost

Comment: im an amateur, so i came for assistance.

Comment: We would need to know what `lst_Age` is and what it is you're adding to it.

Comment: see, now that is the first mention of a "list check box"  do you mean a `CheckedListBox`?  Those will have `Selectedxxxx` and `Checkedxxx` properties - but it also means that they could check both Adult and Senior, for `175D`

Comment: @JimClothier assuming you're using a CheckedListBox there is a property [`CheckedItems`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.checkeditems(v=vs.110).aspx) from where you can check if the one you want is. What that also tells is that they are a lot of information missing to grasp the exact context of the question

Comment: I'll check out the CheckedItems Property to see if that will fix my error. Thank You All for being patient, i know java better then i know VB. Teacher in VB isnt the best at college, so i have been relying on the internet to learn

Comment: For a selection which is mutually exclusive, (pick one: {Standard, Adult, Senior}) you probably want to use a ComboBox

Comment: In addition to all that, your last three lines can be simplified.  Since Cost(3) is already a decimal, you don't need the variable Output at all,.  Just write:    lbl_Output.Text =Cost(3).ToString()

Comment: As a new user, you definitely want to read [Ask], the [FAQ] and take the [Tour]

Comment: @Plutonix Couldn't fix the title?

Comment: @LarsTech maybe `If "Adults (18-64)" = 1` comparison not working ?

Comment: @JimClothier turn on **Option Strict** as mentioned in a previous comment. This will help you more than you think. Also have a think about your constants. You may want `Boolean` instead of `Decimal` with **VBChecked** and **VBUnchecked**. If you're new to VB.NET then Google anything you struggle with. There is loads of resources out there now.

Comment: An accurate title would be "Please do my homework for me"

Comment: I'd suggest 'Membership' should be radiobuttons as (presumably) the user should only select one option.